# How find users in database with same content in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model-view-controller

In my database I have column **:inviter** and some users have same content in that column

**I want find all them,with same content**

In my user controller:

```
  def foll
    @user = current_user
    @ref = User.find_by_invite(@user.id.to_s)
    if !@ref || !@ref.pay_s || !@ref.pay_1 || !@ref.pay_2 || !@ref.pay_3
      @referals = false
    else
      @referals = User.find_by_invite(@user.id.to_s)
    end
  end
```

In my views

```
<% if @referals != false %>
  <% @referals.each do |user| %>
      <h4>
        <%= link_to user.name, user %> status : Good
      </h4>
  <% end %>
  <% else %>
  <h3>You dont have any referrals</h3>
  <% end %>
```

When I try I have this error

```
undefined method `each' for #<User:0x007f13e41b0068>
```

Comment: When you do `find_by` in rails it will find the *first* record that matches the specified conditions. Use `where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help:

controller:

```
  def foll
    @user = current_user
    @ref = User.find_by_invite(@user.id.to_s)
    if !@ref || !@ref.pay_s || !@ref.pay_1 || !@ref.pay_2 || !@ref.pay_3
      @referals = []
    else
      @referals = User.where(invite: @user.id.to_s)
    end
  end
```

view:

```
<% if @referals.any? %>
  <% @referals.each do |user| %>
      <h4>
        <%= link_to user.name, user %> status : Good
      </h4>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <h3>You dont have any referrals</h3>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

this will raise error since

```
@referals = User.find_by_invite(@user.id.to_s)
```

will return single record

you can try #where to query all referrals

```
@referals = User.where(invite: @user.id.to_s)
```

you can also refer here for other queries
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
hope this helps